# Apply With LinkedIn Module 2

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

We want to add an Apply with linkedin feature to a website. Do we need to apply anywhere on LinkedIn for this? How should we proceed to apply?

We filled out the form at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-connect, but they said they can answer from the stackoverflow site.